# Manipular Requisição HTTP tendo Array de itens como resposta

Tags: json, array, angular, typescript

Opa, tudo bem galera?

Talvez essa pergunte não ajude ninguém, mas não sei mas o que fazer, vocês aqui do StackOverflow são minha esperança.

Seguinte, na página que estou montando, irá mostrar todos os planos que uma academia tem com o valor, nome, parcelas e etc...

Esse é o JSON:

```
{
    "Registros": 4,
    "Itens": [
        {
            "ItemOnlineID": "2",
            "ItemID": "51",
            "ItemNome": "CROSS FIT ECONOMICO",
            "ItemTipoID": "101",
            "ItemTipo": "MENSAL",
            "ItemRecorrencia": "1",
            "ItemMatriculaID": null,
            "ItemMatriculaDescricao": null,
            "ItemMatriculaValor": null,
            "ItemLink": "vendas.academiaweb.com.br/BrfitPampulha-949-2",
            "ItemValores": [
                {
                    "ItemValorID": "56",
                    "ItemValorQuantidade": "2",
                    "ItemValorPreco": "239.00",
                    "ItemValorLimiteParcelas": "1",
                    "ItemValorDescontoID": null,
                    "ItemValorDescontoDescricao": null,
                    "ItemValorPrecoDesconto": null
                },
                {
                    "ItemValorID": "57",
                    "ItemValorQuantidade": "3",
                    "ItemValorPreco": "259.00",
                    "ItemValorLimiteParcelas": "1",
                    "ItemValorDescontoID": null,
                    "ItemValorDescontoDescricao": null,
                    "ItemValorPrecoDesconto": null
                },
                {
                    "ItemValorID": "58",
                    "ItemValorQuantidade": "5",
                    "ItemValorPreco": "279.00",
                    "ItemValorLimiteParcelas": "1",
                    "ItemValorDescontoID": null,
                    "ItemValorDescontoDescricao": null,
                    "ItemValorPrecoDesconto": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ItemOnlineID": "4",
            "ItemID": "40",
            "ItemNome": "PILATES+AEROBICO",
            "ItemTipoID": "101",
            "ItemTipo": "MENSAL",
            "ItemRecorrencia": "0",
            "ItemMatriculaID": null,
            "ItemMatriculaDescricao": null,
            "ItemMatriculaValor": null,
            "ItemLink": "vendas.academiaweb.com.br/BrfitPampulha-949-4",
            "ItemValores": [
                {
                    "ItemValorID": "44",
                    "ItemValorQuantidade": "1",
                    "ItemValorPreco": "284.00",
                    "ItemValorLimiteParcelas": "1",
                    "ItemValorDescontoID": null,
                    "ItemValorDescontoDescricao": null,
                    "ItemValorPrecoDesconto": null
                },
                {
                    "ItemValorID": "45",
                    "ItemValorQuantidade": "2",
                    "ItemValorPreco": "310.00",
                    "ItemValorLimiteParcelas": "1",
                    "ItemValorDescontoID": null,
                    "ItemValorDescontoDescricao": null,
                    "ItemValorPrecoDesconto": null
                },
                {
                    "ItemValorID": "46",
                    "ItemValorQuantidade": "3",
                    "ItemValorPreco": "345.00",
                    "ItemValorLimiteParcelas": "1",
                    "ItemValorDescontoID": null,
                    "ItemValorDescontoDescricao": null,
                    "ItemValorPrecoDesconto": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ItemOnlineID": "1",
            "ItemID": "11",
            "ItemNome": "ARTES MARCIAIS",
            "ItemTipoID": "102",
            "ItemTipo": "PLANO",
            "ItemRecorrencia": "1",
            "ItemMatriculaID": "7",
            "ItemMatriculaDescricao": "TAXA DE ADESAO ARTES MARCIAIS",
            "ItemMatriculaValor": "35.00",
            "ItemLink": "vendas.academiaweb.com.br/BrfitPampulha-949-1",
            "ItemValores": [
                {
                    "ItemValorID": "36",
                    "ItemValorQuantidade": "6",
                    "ItemValorPreco": "840.00",
                    "ItemValorLimiteParcelas": "6",
                    "ItemValorDescontoID": null,
                    "ItemValorDescontoDescricao": null,
                    "ItemValorPrecoDesconto": null
                },
                {
                    "ItemValorID": "27",
                    "ItemValorQuantidade": "12",
                    "ItemValorPreco": "1500.00",
                    "ItemValorLimiteParcelas": "12",
                    "ItemValorDescontoID": "2",
                    "ItemValorDescontoDescricao": "CONVENIOS",
                    "ItemValorPrecoDesconto": "1200.000000000000000000000000000000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ItemOnlineID": "3",
            "ItemID": "10",
            "ItemNome": "PILATES 3X",
            "ItemTipoID": "102",
            "ItemTipo": "PLANO",
            "ItemRecorrencia": "1",
            "ItemMatriculaID": null,
            "ItemMatriculaDescricao": null,
            "ItemMatriculaValor": null,
            "ItemLink": "vendas.academiaweb.com.br/BrfitPampulha-949-3",
            "ItemValores": [
                {
                    "ItemValorID": "25",
                    "ItemValorQuantidade": "3",
                    "ItemValorPreco": "858.00",
                    "ItemValorLimiteParcelas": "3",
                    "ItemValorDescontoID": null,
                    "ItemValorDescontoDescricao": null,
                    "ItemValorPrecoDesconto": null
                },
                {
                    "ItemValorID": "26",
                    "ItemValorQuantidade": "6",
                    "ItemValorPreco": "1620.00",
                    "ItemValorLimiteParcelas": "6",
                    "ItemValorDescontoID": null,
                    "ItemValorDescontoDescricao": null,
                    "ItemValorPrecoDesconto": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ErrMsg": ""
}
```

Como podem ver, Itens é um array de objetos que possui 4 items, dentro de cada um possui outro array de objetos "ItemValores".

Qual é o problema, preciso mostrar ou esconder coisas baseado em certos items dentro desse Array como por exemplo:

No item 1 ("ItemOnlineID = 2") o plano não possui desconto ("ItemValorPrecoDesconto = null") então eu devo exibir o ("ItemValorPreco")

Mas se possui desconto, como no item 3 ("ItemOnlineID = 1"), ao invés do ("ItemValorPreco") devo exibir ("ItemValorPrecoDesconto"), e não faço a mínima ideia de como fazer isso.

Meu código tá assim:

```js
planos.ts

export class Planos {
  itens: any[];
  planoNome: string;
  planoTipo: string;
  ItemValores = {
    planoQuantidade: '',
    planoPreco: '',
    planoLimiteParcelas: '',
    planoPrecoDesconto: '',
  };
}
```

```js
plano.service.ts

export class PlanoService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  async receberPlanos(planos) {
    await this.http
      .get(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => {
        planos.itens = res.Itens;
        // ***Para acessar cada um dos 4 items dentro do Array de objetos "Itens"***
        for (const e in planos.itens) {
          planos.planoNome = res.Itens[e].ItemNome;
          planos.planoTipo = res.Itens[e].ItemTipo;
        // ***Para acessar cada um dos items dentro do Array de objetos "ItemValores" dentro de "Itens"***
          for (const i in planos.itens[e].ItemValores) {
            planos.ItemValores.planoQuantidade = res.Itens[e].ItemValores[i].ItemValorQuantidade;
            planos.ItemValores.planoPreco = res.Itens[e].ItemValores[i].ItemValorPreco;
            planos.ItemValores.planoLimiteParcelas = res.Itens[e].ItemValores[i].ItemValorLimiteParcelas;
            planos.ItemValores.planoPrecoDesconto = res.Itens[e].ItemValores[i].ItemValorPrecoDesconto;

          }
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Mas como é um Array de objetos, o item "planoNome" por exemplo, vai de fato receber cada um dos nomes dos planos, mas vai permanecer com o último.

Então como fazer essas checagens? Estou completamente perdido.

Comment: Não da pra tratar isso no seu component e usar um if pra verificar cada objeto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode efetuar dois *loops*, um para listar o nome do plano e outro para listar os pacotes. Para tratar a exibição do preço com ou sem desconto basta utilizar uma lógica bem simples com o `*ngIf` (não esqueça de importar o `CommonModule` para utilizá-lo). Veja por exemplo o template abaixo:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of meusDados">
  {{item.ItemNome}}
  <div *ngFor="let a of item.ItemValores">
    <span *ngIf="a.ItemValorPrecoDesconto">
      {{a.ItemValorPrecoDesconto}}
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="!a.ItemValorPrecoDesconto">
      {{a.ItemValorPreco}}
    </span>
  </div>
  <hr />
</div>
```

E no código TS do seu componente:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DadosService } from './dados.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  meusDados: Array<any> = [];

  constructor(private dadosService: DadosService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Retorna exatamente o JSON que você postou
    this.dadosService.getDados()
      .subscribe(dados => {
        this.meusDados = dados.Itens;
      });
  }
}
```

Na *service* você não precisa mapear "na mão" os dados retornados, basta criar uma(s) interface(s) que represente seu modelo de dados e utilizá-la no `get. 
Código da *service* que eu criei para simular seu problema:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class DadosService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  getDados() {
    return this.http
      // Ao invés do "any" crie uma interface para mapear seu modelo de dados
      .get<any>('https://5e163b0422b5c600140cf959.mockapi.io/aaa');
  }
}
```

Comment: Mas eu utilizei uma interface, utilizei esse site: http://www.jsontots.com e colei aquele JSON lá.